# Pyqtgraph error when running built in examples

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to work out how to use pyqtgraph so that I can use it.

I've tried to run this block of code which I found on the pyqtgraph website

```
import pyqtgraph.examples
pyqtgraph.examples.run()
```

But it always throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/willemhandreck/Code/Misc.Projects/heater_alert/python/plotly_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyqtgraph.examples
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .Qt import QtGui
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/Qt.py", line 35, in <module>
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtOpenGL, QtSvg
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so, 2): Library not loaded: libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so
  Reason: image not found
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: How did you install PyQtGraph? easy_install? Did you install PySide?

Do the file directories exist?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I used pip to install pyqtgraph and pyside and yes all those directories are there. Does the '2' in the dlopen() function have any significance?

Comment: Just wondering at the meantime as I've found this error unsolved on 2 other forums spanning 4 years of time:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/8814/solved-pyside-new-mac-os-install-can-t-load-qtcore-so

Let me get on my Mac with a fresh install and see if I can troubleshoot this. I was wondering perhaps if something wasn't built, but if you installed with pip, should be fine.

Comment: If you have multiple copies of Python installed, then make sure you are running the version for which you installed PySide and PyQtGraph. It looks here like you are running OSX's built-in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, same problem here if I try to use the built-in python on the mac.

My solution is to use the anaconda python distribution:

1) Download & install Anaconda python, which already has all the right scientific modules installed.  http://continuum.io/downloads#all

2) Restart your terminal and ensure you have anaconda as your python:

```
$ which python
/Users/caleb/anaconda/bin/python
```

3) Then install pyqtgraph:

```
$ pip install pyqtgraph
... 
Successfully installed pyqtgraph-0.9.10
```

4) Run the examples from the command line:

```
$ python -m pyqtgraph.examples
```

or use your import... run method above.

-Caleb

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a good thing. 
The system python ships installed and configured to run system utilities. It's a good idea to have a separate playpen for special packages, tweaks, upgrades, experiments.
Anaconda makes it autoeasy by containing itself and its packages all within its own directory and prevents messing up anything else.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/39qeq6/anaconda_pros_cons_mac_os_x/cs5mxwk